# Solidity error message when executing smart contract: "the constructor should be payable if you send value"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to learn solidity through coding the smart contract below (see snippet below) .
I have been able to successfully compile (i.e. without bugs) the smart contract, the object of which is to payout an inheritance from one ethereum wallet address to another (e.g. a family member).
I have also been able to deploy it but I get the following error message (also see attached pic) when i try to transfer an inheritance to a payee.
Any help is greatly appreciated !

error message:
"transact to Will.setInheritance errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information"

```js
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

//Use a double forward slash to write a like this one
// Line1 : First we nominate which version of the SOLIDITY code we are using.
//This is always the first step in our code.
// Here we tell REMIX that the the source code we are using is version 0.5.1 or above (by using the ^ - carrot symbol)

// We will start building our SC which will eventually split the inheritance of a persons will (e.g. Grandfather) amongst the Family members


contract Will {
//Line 9 : Each new contract must be named as  “contract”, then the name with the first letter always CAPITALIZED, followed by open/close curly brackets to contain the logic. 


    address owner;
    uint fortune;
    bool isDeceased;

// Line 13: here we declare the variables of the smart contract - each variable must be listed along with its variable type in SOLIDITY
// Line 13: owner is of the address type of variable in SOLIDITY (unique variable in SOLIDITY - refers to an ethereum network address)
// Line 14: fortune is of the type uint (unsigned integer = a positive only integer)
// Line 15: isDeceased is a boolean variable (i.e. TRUE or FALSE type)

    constructor() public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
        fortune = msg.value;
        isDeceased = false;
    }
    

// Line 22: here we use a constructor function to set these values in he contract
// The “public” keyword is what’s known as a “visibility modifier” which tells the contract who is allowed to call the function. 
// Public means that the function can be called within the contract and outside of it by someone else or another contract.
// The “payable” keyword allows the function to send and receive ether. 
// When we deploy the contract we can initialize it with an ether balance. 
// When the contract receives ether, it will store it in its own address.
// Then we will use the SC to transfer the ether to another adress (or inheritor)
// Line 23:  we set the owner to “msg.sender”, which is a built-in global variable representative of the address that is calling the function. 
//In this case, it will be the owner of the funds.
// Line 24: The fortune is set to “msg.value”, which is another built-in variable that tells us how much ether has been sent.
// Line 25: We set the isDeceased to false 
    
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require (msg.sender ==owner);
        _;
    }

        
    modifier mustBeDeceased {
        require (isDeceased == true);
        _;
    }
    
// Modifiers are add-ons to functions that contain conditional logic. 
// Line 41 declares “onlyOwner” modifier. 
// If added to a function, it can only be called if the caller (msg.sender) is equivalent to the owner variable as stated above (remember how we set the owner in the constructor). We will need this to allow the distribution of funds, which will be implemented later.
// The “require” keyword states that we want isDeceased to be true otherwise solidity will throw an error and the execution will stop. 
// The “_;” at the end tells the execution to shift to the actual function after it’s done reading the modifier.


// Now we must declare how the inheritance is divided amongst the family members. 
// We will need their public wallet keys (addresses) and their desired allotments.
// First we create a list to store the wallet addresses (of the family members) 
// And we create a and a function that sets the inheritance for each address.
    
    
    address payable[] wallets;
    
    //ABOVE WE HAVE TO ENTER payable to tell SOLIDITY that the address for the payout of the money is the wallet address
    // function will not work without adding "address" here 
    
    mapping (address => uint) inheritance;
    
    function setInheritance(address payable _wallet, uint _inheritance) public onlyOwner {
        wallets.push(_wallet);
        inheritance [_wallet] = _inheritance;
    }
    
    
// Line 67: declares an empty array called “wallets” for storing the family members’ wallet addresses. 
// This is a list-like data structure . The square brackets after “address” indicate it’s an array of items rather than a single variable.
// Line 69: Creates a mapping from an address type to a uint type named “inheritance” 
// We will use this for distributing the inheritance to a family members wallet (It’s the equivalent of a “dictionary” in other languages such as Python and Javascript, Key/Value Pair).
    
// Line 71 declares the function that adds an address to the (empty) inheritance array we just created and then sets the inheritance to be provided to this address. 
// We added the the “onlyOwner” modifier we added to this function, which means that only the owner of the money can distribute the funds 

// Finally we create the payout function, i.e. the actual transfer of the funds

    function payout() private mustBeDeceased {
        for (uint i=0; i<wallets.length; i++) {
            wallets[i].transfer(inheritance[wallets[i]]);
        }
    }
    
    function deceased() public payable onlyOwner {
        isDeceased = true;
        payout();
    }
}
```

[Solidity error message i receive when i try to transfer the payment to the payee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEUu8.png)

Comment: Please share the actual error message you got, not a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for response, the error message is "The constructor should be payable is you send value"

Comment: That's part of the error message, yes (well, with a typo). The rest tells you that your transaction was reverted and what method you were calling (both vital pieces of information).

Comment: `setInheritance` SHOULD BE `payable`.

Answer (score 2):

I executed your code and examine in depth. Note that currently remix and solidity does not show good and meaningful error messages.

The problem here is your constructor function is payable:

```
constructor() public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
        fortune = msg.value;
        isDeceased = false;
    }
```

And if you execute `constructor` without any value it will execute also the `setInheritance` will execute without error and when you try to run the `deceased` function which is another payable function, then the things will blast. The remix will say the constructor is payable but did not sent any value.

Please try to send some `value` if you want to run any `payable function`. Here you can write value for payable functions. 
[image]

Hope it helps.